# How to count and check passed arguments?

Tags: ruby, bash, command-line

How can I translate the following Ruby code to Bash?

```
if ARGV.length == 0
    abort "\nError: The project name is required. Aborting...\n\n"
elsif ARGV.length > 2
    abort "\nError: The program takes two arguments maximum. Aborting...\n\n"
end
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
#!/bin/bash
USAGE="$0: <project name> [subproject attribute]"
if [ $# -lt 1 ]; then echo -e "Error: The project name is required.\n$USAGE" >&2; exit 1; fi
if [ $# -gt 2 ]; then echo -e "Error: Two arguments maximum.\n$USAGE" >&2; exit 1; fi
```

Comment: Thanks but what's the "-e" it's being printed when exiting.

Comment: @emurad: That is to allow interpolation of the \n escape so that I can print your message and the USAGE in one echo statement.  If your echo does not understand -e, it is very old.  Just have multiple prints.

Answer (score 4):

The following should be what you need:

```bsh
#!/bin/bash
if [ $# -eq 0 ]; then
  echo -e "\nError: The project name is required. Aborting...\n\n"
  exit 1
elif [ $# -gt 2 ]; then
  echo -e "\nError: The program takes two arguments maximum. Aborting...\n\n"
  exit 1
fi
```

The TLDP bash guide is very good if you are looking to learn bash, see [TDLP Bash guide](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/).

Comment: This too, "-e" is being printed when exiting.

Comment: As Seth Robertson said, you probably have a very old version of the echo command, or some non-GNU version. If you do "man echo" then copy what it says right at the bottom, then maybe we can tell you why that's occurring. So I have `GNU coreutils 8.5                  June 2010                           ECHO(1)`.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe:

```
#!/bin/bash

function functionName {
if [ $# = 0 ]
then echo "\nError: The project name is required. Aborting...\n\n"; exit 1
fi

if [ $# \> 2 ]
then echo "\nError: The program takes two arguments maximum. Aborting...\n\n"; exit 1
fi

}

functionName a
```

Comment: Anyone who attempts to run `[ $# > 2 ]` is going to be very surprised the next time they run ls.